# How to have two layout xml files in a single activity in android

Tags: android

I am developing application in android.What I want is ,my activity should represent two xml layouts files.concept is like,
           ->when the activity is started it should show one layout(screen)
           ->when I click on the button exist on the first layout, it should show 2nd layout in the bottom of the screen,keeping first layout visible.

Comment: You requirement will be fulfilled by `Fragment` I guess...

Comment: For this, You don't need to design two xml layouts. Please share any screen shot here.

Answer (score 4):

Have both the layout in a single XML. Keep the visibility of the the second layout to `secondLayoutObject.setVisibility(View.GONE)` initially and then on the click of the button change its visibility to `secondLayoutObject.setVisibility(View.Visible)`.

Comment: How to Have both the layout in a single XML. it gives me error when i tried

Comment: You can certainly have 2 layouts one below the other. If you are getting an error try having a container/parent layout inside which you can specify the two different layouts.

Answer (score 1):

On method to call two xml files in on activity is by using layoutmanager and assign the screen  ratio for both xml files. Use relative layout in both xml. Small code snippet is

```
RelativeLayout layleft = (RelativeLayout)inf.inflate(R.layout.firstxml,null);
        RelativeLayout layright = (RelativeLayout)inf.inflate(R.layout.secondxml,null);
```

for detail info [Layout Reuse help](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use the concept of visibility. Initially set visibility of second layout as GONE and when you press button set Its visibility True.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use the bellow example:

https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android

this source code to change layout like button click to load another layout!